# JSON property with hyphen in it in ServiceStack

Tags: json, serialization, servicestack, dto

I have some `JSON` formed like this:

```
 {
  "snippet-format":"raw",
  "total":1,"start":1,
  "page-length":200, ... 
 }
```

I have a C# DTO with members called Total, Start etc. These are successfully having the values from the above placed in to them. I don't know how to name properties for the snippet-format and page-length JSON items above though.

I've tried SnippetFormat and Snippet_Format to no avail.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Also, if a value happens to be a `W3C xs:dateTime string`, is there a type I can use that `ServiceStack` will automatically populate for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Checked into the next version](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/29a764724bce0b7d8ba08b741115ec5ff67792ef) of ServiceStack.Text v3.9.43+, the Lenient property convention now supports hyphened properties, so you will be able to do:

```
public class Hyphens
{
    public string SnippetFormat { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int PageLength { get; set; }
}

JsConfig.PropertyConvention = JsonPropertyConvention.Lenient;

var json = @"{
    ""snippet-format"":""raw"",
    ""total"":1,
    ""start"":1,
    ""page-length"":200
 }";

var dto = json.FromJson<Hyphens>();

Assert.That(dto.SnippetFormat, Is.EqualTo("raw"));
Assert.That(dto.Total, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(dto.Start, Is.EqualTo(1));
Assert.That(dto.PageLength, Is.EqualTo(200));
```

In the meantime you will have to parse it dynamically, e.g:

```
var map = JsonObject.Parse(json);
Assert.That(map["snippet-format"], Is.EqualTo("raw"));
Assert.That(map["total"], Is.EqualTo("1"));
Assert.That(map["start"], Is.EqualTo("1"));
Assert.That(map["page-length"], Is.EqualTo("200"));
```

Comment: Lenient sounds exactly like what I need. If I need to create a JSON document from this class too though (E.g. for a PUT), can I add something to the class to instruct ServiceStack to use a hyphen when serialising?

Comment: Not a hypen, there's only [JsConfig.EmitLowerCaseNames and lower with underscores](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs#L284-L318). Check with `JsConfig` to see all of ServiceStack's text serializers supported features.

Comment: Did you not check the link? `JsConfig.EmitLowercaseUnderscoreNames` is highlighted.